# VBA Find method setting ranges from strings inaccurately

Tags: excel, vba

I am receiving inaccurate date values in a VBA loop.  The code I am using is below.  I have a table of start dates and end dates some of which are February dates begining in "02".  With all dates in the table that begin with "02" I am receiving string values that start with "12" with the remaining portion of the date the same.  It looks as though there may be an error in the data type or something else.  How can I define the dates as they are so that I may return accurate dates as they are written in the cells in the worksheet?  Thanks!

```
Dim aa As Integer
Dim StartDate As String
Dim EndDate As String
Dim RngStart As Range
Dim RngEnd  As Range
Dim RngStartR As String
Dim RngStartRng As Range
Dim RngEndR As String
Dim RngEndRng As Range
Dim RngXR As String:  RngXR 
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ActiveSheet").Range("C7").value
Dim RngXR2 As String:           RngXR2 = 
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ActiveSheet").Range("C8").value
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim chrt As ChartObject
Dim ch As Chart
Dim zz As Integer
Dim NumObs2 As Long

NumObs2 = Sheets("AllDistanceMeasures").Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row

For aa = 5 To NumObs2

StartDate = Sheets("AllDistanceMeasures").Cells(aa, 9).value
EndDate = Sheets("AllDistanceMeasures").Cells(aa, 10).value

    If StartDate <> "" Then

        Set RngStart = Sheets("ActiveSheet").Cells.Find(What:=StartDate, 
After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, 1)

    Else
        MsgBox "StartDate variable for " & 
Sheets("AllDistanceMeasures").Cells(aa, 9).Address & " not found", 
vbExclamation
        Exit Sub

    End If

    RngStartR = RngStart.Address

    If EndDate <> "" Then

        Set RngEnd = Sheets("ActiveSheet").Cells.Find(What:=EndDate, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, 1)

    Else
        MsgBox "EndDate variable for " & Sheets("AllDistanceMeasures").Cells(aa, 10).Address & " not found", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub

    End If

    RngEndR = RngEnd.Address

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("LowDistCharts").Activate

Set sh = Worksheets("LowDistCharts")
Set chrt = sh.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, 300, 300)
Set ch = chrt.Chart

Do While ch.SeriesCollection.Count > 1

    ch.SeriesCollection(1).Delete

Loop

    With chrt
        .Height = 300
        .Width = 300
        .Top = 1 + ((aa - 4) * 300)
        .Left = 1
    End With

    With ch
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = aa & " " & StartDate & " to " & EndDate
        .ChartTitle.Font.Size = 8
        .ChartType = xlLine
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ActiveSheet").Range(RngXR, RngXR2)
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(2).Values = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ActiveSheet").Range(RngStartR, RngEndR)
        .SeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2
        .SeriesCollection(3).Delete
        .HasLegend = False
    End With

    For zz = 0 To NumObs - 1

        Sheets("ActiveSheet").Range(RngEndR).Offset(zz, 0).Copy
        Sheets("LowDistCharts").Cells(5, aa + 5).Offset(zz, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Next zz

Next aa
```

Comment: You'll want to paste **exactly** the code that you're using. The code you pasted currently does not compile. Problem starting at line `Dim RngXR As String:  RngXR`

Comment: If date is not correctly entered in excel, it will be either be saved as string, which has to be converted to date if any calculation is to be performed on it or it will be saved incorrectly i.e. month can be day or day can be month, even then it has to be converted first to correct date before doing something else. You have to write some code first to fix the dates as per what you have and what sort of conversion is required, after that you can run your original macro

Comment: you'll want to throw in an underscore there for it to compile properly.  @usmanhaq I'll work with it to see if I can run bits of code before running the loop to affect format in the worksheet. thanks

Comment: @usmanhaq could you elaborate on approaches to handling the dates?  I've tried a few things: formatting columns, changing variable types, and use of CDate prior to setting values.  None of these seem to be working and I haven't been able to find precedent online.  If I can repeat back to you to make sure I am understanding correctly, I need to affect the data type at some point, either in the sheet or in the code and then run it.  Is that what you are in essence saying?

Comment: You can not fix the wrong dates using formatting or CDate, because it is a wrong entry. It depends upon how the users have entered the data, if you can show me some samples of how your dates are entered, i can recommend some solution.

Comment: the dates are entered MM/DD/YY .07/22/10 08/25/10
10/27/10 12/01/10
11/18/09 12/23/09
01/06/10 02/10/10
05/09/08 06/13/08
02/20/08 03/26/08
07/26/18 08/29/18  So for instance the date beginning in "02" is the "what:=" value in the "find" method but instead of returning the correct date it selects a date with the first two values "12".  Im stumped!